# DMARC, SAP and impacts to emails from individuals

Tags: email, sap, dmarc

Our company recently implemented DMARC and we are working through impacts to SFMC.  We just purchased an SAP with the domain email.company.com. We send a lot of auto-sincerity emails - so emails that appear to come from an individual.

Prior to DMARC and the SAP, we sent with the domain @company.com.  Now, in order to meet DMARC, we need to send these from @email.company.com.  however we have the following concerns:

Email recipients would get non-SFMC emails from john.doe@company.com and SFMC emails from john.doe@email.company.com which out not provide a good user experience as it could

- cause confusion as to why there are 2 emails
- they may be unsure as to which email to send emails to
- emails from email.company.com would be easier to identify as not personalized since it is not their actual email address
- the "From" email would not match the signature block: ie:
  From Email: john.doe@email.company.com
  From: John Doe

> Subject: sample email
>
> sample body
>
> Sincerely, John Doe john.doe@company.com

How are others handling this?

Answer (score 1):

The domain or subdomain (email.company.com) used for the Sender Authentication Package needs to be exclusively used for Marketing Cloud only. You have to delegate the DNS entries to ExactTarget mail servers. In your case, you have two options that I can think of:

1. Add john.doe as a Sender Profile and send from SFMC with john.doe@email.company.com
2. Communicate with the customer that they will receive emails from the domain (company.com) or subdomain (email.company.com).

For option 1, that would mean that your internal users would have to log into the SFMC platform for email sends.

I personally think it's a non-issue as the parent domain is the same and you're just using the subdomain of email.company.com for SFMC sends.